# Sleep after ZMQ connect?

Tags: python, sleep, zeromq

In a ROUTER-ROUTER setup, after I connect one ROUTER socket to another, if I don't sleep (for say 0.1s or so) after I `connect()` to the other ROUTER socket, the `send()` usually doesn't go through (although it sometimes does, by chance).

1. Is there a way to make sure I am connected before I send?
2. Why aren't the `send()`s queued and properly executed until the connection is made?

Also, this is not about whether the server on the other end is alive but rather that I `send()` too soon after I `connect()` and somehow it fails. I am not sure why.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to make sure I am connected before I send?

Not directly.  The recommended approach is to use something like the [Freelanch Protocol](http://rfc.zeromq.org/spec:10) and keep pinging until you receive a response.  If you stop receiving responses to your pings you should consider yourself disconnected.

> Why aren't the send()s queued and properly executed until the connection is made?

A router cannot send a message to a peer until both sides have completed an internal ZeroMQ handshake.  That's just the way it works, since the ROUTER requires the ID of its peer in order to "route".  Apparently sleeping for .1sec is the right amount of time on your dev system. If you need the ability to connect and then send without sleeping or retrying, then you need to use a different pattern.

For example, with DEALER-ROUTER, a DEALER client can connect and immediately send and ZeroMQ will queue the message until it is delivered. The reason the works is that the DEALER does not require the ID of the peer - since it does not "route". When the ROUTER server receives the message, that handshake is already complete so it can respond right away without sleeping.

Comment: Oh okay makes sense ... so what you are saying is that if I try to send too early, it just won't queue it? Maybe the question should be: If I want a many-to-many connection should I use some other pattern or should I use ROUTER-ROUTER like I am now?

Comment: Yes the message is dropped.  At least thats how I interpreted the zguide.zeromq.org.  Also, the guide has a bunch of warnings about the difficulties of using ROUTER-ROUTER, so it would be worth the time to investigate other patterns (there are tons), even if it means rethinking your approach.  FYI - I never use ROUTER-ROUTER.  I use DEALER-ROUTER for everything.

Comment: I do actually want many-to-many and FLP seems to fit well. I basically have a bunch of servers serving same/similar/related data/services and a bunch of clients using that data to do something and if one of the servers goes down, the clients can connect to one of the others ... also, the clients might connect to different servers for different *kinds* of requests. Is there some other pattern I might be able to use for that?